Find unique solution to noninvertible system of linear equations, subject to constraints
I have the following problem:
I have a directed graph with $M$ nodes and $K$ edges. Each edge $E_j$ has a weight $w_{1,j} + w_{0, j}$ at the end of the edge and $w_{0, j}$ at the start of the edge. The values for $w_{1,j}$ are known for each edge, I am trying to calculate all the $w_{0, j}$.
The graph must satisfy the condition, that the sum of all weights of incoming and outgoing edges in each node must equal $0$. $d_{ij}$ denotes the adjacency of edge $E_j$ to node $N_i$:

$d_{ij}=0$ if $E_j$ is not connected to node $N_i$
$d_{ij}=1$ if $E_j$ points into $N_i$
$d_{ij} =-1$ if $E_j$ points out of $N_i$

I can write this system of equations as:
$$\mathbf{D} \vec{w}_0 + \mathbf{A}\vec{w}_1 = \vec{0}$$
where $\mathbf{D}$ contains all the $d_{ij}$ and $a_{ij} = 1$ if $d_{ij} = 1$, else $a_{ij} = 0$.
The number of loops in the graph $L$ can be calculated as $L = K + 1 - M$, and there are $L$ additional constraints of the shape:
$$\mathbf{Q}\vec{w}_0=\vec{v}$$
So I get a system that reads:
$$\mathbf{D} \vec{w}_0 = - \mathbf{A}\vec{w}_1 \text{  subject to  } \mathbf{Q}\vec{w}_0=\vec{v}$$
where in most cases, $\mathbf{D}$, $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$ are not square.
I know of a way to solve this, however it involves very tedious manipulation of $\mathbf{D}$ and introduction of additional variables. Is there a way of solving this directly?

So...$-Aw_1$ can be thought of more abstractly as $b$, so you have $[D;Q]w_0=[b;v]$ to abuse Matlab notation. $D$ is $M \times K$, $Q$ is $(K+1-M) \times K$, so the overall system is $(K+1) \times K$. Presumably the redundancy is in $D$, because $D$ has all column sums equal to zero. Can you figure out how to use that to eliminate one of the equations? Once you do that, the whole system is square.

What does it mean to have a weight at the start of an edge and a different weight at the end of an edge?    Normally we associate each edge with a single weight.  What does it mean to refer to "the weight of an edge" (or sum of weights of some particular edges) given this fact?   What does "solving this" mean?  What values are given, and what values are you trying to find?

@Ian Thanks! That solves the problem. The redundancy is definitely in $D$ and I found a Python module for my application that tells me exactly which row of $D$ I can remove without losing information, so I don't have to keep track of it myself.

@D.W. In this specific case, it deals with shear flows in thin-walled bending beams that I try to encode as graphs. The shear flow changes along a segment, so the weight is different at the start node and end node.

Since $A$ and $w_1$ are both given, one can look at the first equation as just $Dw_0 = b$ where $b=-Aw_1$, and then the second equation is $Qw_0=v$. This overall system is $M+K+1-M=K+1$ equations in $K$ unknowns.
You can probably just solve it as is without even changing it provided you use a method like least squares. But to understand the mathematics, you should find how to modify the system to make it have only $K$ equations without adding any new solutions. Presumably there is some redundant equation. I would guess that can be found inside the $Dw_0=b$ system, because $D$ has all column sums equal to zero.
